# Simple Perl: can't compare array elements to strings

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I initially wrote a script to convert a wordlist(each line is just 1 word) into an array of words @keywords(each line an element) using:

```
-------------------

    open (FH, "< $keyword_file") or die "Can't open $keyword_file for read: $!";
    my @keywords;
    while (<FH>) {
        push (@keywords, $_);
    }
    close FH or die "Cannot close $keyword_file: $!";

--------------------
```

I am now trying to use regex to compare this with other strings, but i just keep getting false results for some reason?

```
-----------------------

FULL PROGRAM
    -----------------------------------
    #!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;



print "\n[Keywords]";

my $keyword_file = "keywords.txt";

#read keywords
my @keywords;

open (FH, "$keyword_file") or die "Can't open $keyword_file for read: $!";

while (<FH>) {
    chomp;
    push (@keywords, $_);
}
close FH or die "Cannot close $keyword_file: $!";


#pattern match


foreach(@keywords)
{

   if ("print" =~ m/$_/) {
        print "match found\n";
    }

}


    ----------------------------------
```

the above argument is supposed to be true but it just keeps returning false. What am i doing wrong? Is this because the array is storing nextlines(enter) as well (sorry if i sound ignorant for thinking this :p)?

Comment: What is your interpretation of the regex here? If you intend to compare words in array with `print exit write` then you need to do `if ($_ =~ /print|exit|write/) ... `

Comment: There is no 'print' or 'exit' or 'write' in your keyword file, of course you cannot get any match.

Comment: added the full keyword file

Comment: @QuinnetteRibeiro'college Now it works for me. If it still does not work for you, please update your question to include the whole program that can be use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: just added the full program, thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your array to remove line endings:

```
chomp(@keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to remove the newline in your keywords, try this:

```
while (<FH>) {
    chomp;
    push (@keywords, $_);
}
```

---

Here is a test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @keyword;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    push @keyword, $_;
}

foreach (@keyword) {
    if ("print exit write" =~ m/$_/) {
        print "match found\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
print
exit
write
```

Comment: still doesn't seem to work? When i try to compare an element using something like "text" =~ /$_/ like above it still returns false every time even though 'text' is part of the array?

Comment: @QuinnetteRibeiro'college Then please update your question to include a sample keyword file so I can test my answer with your data.